# Single sql Query with getting Supplier Details

Tags: sql, oracle

A - Supplier Table
B - Supplier Summary Table

I need a sql query which is suitable for this scenario.

If we have data in Supplier Summary Table show the `SupplierId` and `SupplierName`.
If not, show the `SupplierId` and `SupplierName` from Supplier Table.

```
SELECT A.SUPPLIER_ID,B.SUPPLIER_ID
    FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.SUPPLIERS A,
        (SELECT * FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.SUPPLIER_SUMMARY WHERE SUPPLIER_ID = 20)B
    WHERE  B.SUPPLIER_ID   = A.SUPPLIER_ID (+)
```

This is not giving proper Results. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> If we have data in Supplier Summary Table show the `SupplierId` and `SupplierName`.
>    If not, show the `SupplierId` and `SupplierName` from Supplier Table.

```
SELECT COALESCE( B.SUPPLIER_ID, A.SUPPLIER_ID ) AS SUPPLIER_ID,
       COALESCE( B.SUPPLIER_NAME, A.SUPPLIER_NAME ) AS SUPPLIER_NAME
FROM   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.SUPPLIERS A
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       BIZZXE_V2_SCH.SUPPLIER_SUMMARY B
       ON ( A.SUPPLIER_ID   = B.SUPPLIER_ID )
WHERE  A.SUPPLIER_ID = 20;
```

Comment: How is is "not working"? It works fine in this [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef052/1).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT A.SUPPLIER_ID,COALESCE(B.SUPPLIER_ID,A.SUPPLIER_ID)
FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.SUPPLIERS A LEFT JOIN BIZZXE_V2_SCH.SUPPLIER_SUMMARY B on
B.SUPPLIER_ID   = A.SUPPLIER_ID AND SUPPLIER_ID = 20
```